# firebase onDisconnect() is not fired when user lose connection

Tags: firebase, react-native

Hello React native community, I'm trying to use `onDisconnect()` in `firebase` but the problem is that the void isn't getting fired when the network loses its connection but it is working if I close the app or when the app crashes.

This code is working if Wi-Fi is on but it's not working at all if Wi-Fi is off..

```
firebase.database().ref('users/test/connected').onDisconnect().set(false)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine disconnect operations with connection status monitoring and server time stamps to build a user connection status system. On this system, each user stores data in a specific database location to alert the real-time database client to online. The client sets this location to true when it comes online and to time stamp when it disconnects. This timestamp indicates the last time the user was online.

Apps have a disconnect operation ahead of the user's online display, so that there is no contention if the client loses network connectivity before the two commands are sent to the server.

```js
// since I can connect from multiple devices or browser tabs, we store each connection instance separately
// any time that connectionsRef's value is null (i.e. has no children) I am offline
var myConnectionsRef = firebase.database().ref('users/test/connections');

// stores the timestamp of my last disconnect (the last time I was seen online)
var lastOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref('users/test/lastOnline');

var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    // We're connected (or reconnected)! Do anything here that should happen only if online (or on reconnect)
    var con = myConnectionsRef.push();

    // When I disconnect, remove this device
    con.onDisconnect().remove();

    // Add this device to my connections list
    // this value could contain info about the device or a timestamp too
    con.set(true);

    // When I disconnect, update the last time I was seen online
    lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
  }
});
```